# Use state:modified+ selection method in selector with custom path of the metadata.json (dbt)

Tags: dbt

I want to have a selector that is an intersection between another selector and the modified files. I get this working:

```
  - name: main_stores_modified
    definition:
     intersection:
        - method: selector
          value: main_stores
        - method: state
          value: modified
```

But this only works providing that the env variable DBT_STATE is set.

Is it possible to specify the `--state path/to/manifest` within the selector itself?